# Create ID reference for List method from contextual Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community

We have products purchasable for our customers through our Customer Community.  (noob coder here)

Each of them has a custom object record that is called their "Involvement". On the Involvement is a related list called "Extras".

I want to build a class that receives the `recordId` from a lightning component and then shows the "Extras" they have on their "Involvement". 
Eventually, this will expand into only show "Extras" they haven't purchased yet by comparing available Extras (uses SF Products) with the Extras they have purchased and only showing Extras they haven't purchased (we don't want them purchasing the same extra more than once).

However, I can't even get the class started by having the `recordId` inside the class to be able to filter Extras that are related to the Involvement.

**EDIT**
Updated code and add JS ctlr

**I get the error:
void method must not return value**

```
public with sharing class TSVExtras {

@AuraEnabled
public static void getExtrasList(Id invID) {
    List<Extras__c> extrasList = [SELECT Id, Name, Involvement__r.Id, Product__r.Name FROM Extras__c WHERE Involvement__r.Id =: invID];
    return extrasList;
 }
}
```

JS controller

```
 ({
/* Executed when component loads.
 * Populates variables on component page */
initialize: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log (component.get("v.recordId"));


    var action = component.get("c.getExtras");
    action.setParams({"invID": component.get("v.recordId") });// Create a callback that is executed after 
    // the server-side action returns
    $A.enqueueAction(action);


//    helper.getProducts(component);
 }

})
```

Comment: DCole, You are missing parameter for the method while calling it => `Id invID`, can you add js controller code snippet here?

Comment: Updated and added controller. I changed the method in the apex ctlr but just not sure how to get what I'm after for a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to put the set.params call in the helper, even though Salesforce documentation says to put it in the controller. (I don't know why!?!)
This is the post I used as guidance, granted it's 4 years old
[Content-Aware Cmps](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html)

APEX CLASS

```
public with sharing class TSVExtras {
@AuraEnabled 
public static List <Extras__c> getExtras(Id invID) {
    return[SELECT Id,Name, Involvement__c, Product__r.Name
           FROM Extras__c 
           WHERE Involvement__c = :invID
          ];
 }
}
```

LTNG CMP

```
<aura:component controller="TSVExtras" implements="force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global" >

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="extras" type="List" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.extras}" var="ext">

    {!ext.Name} <br/> 
    {!ext.Involvement__c}<br/> <br/>

</aura:iteration>
```

LTNG CONTROLLER

```
({
initialize: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getExtras(component);

  }

 })
```

LTNG HELPER

```
({
// Fetch the Products from the Apex controller
getExtras: function(component) {
    var action = component.get('c.getExtras');
    action.setParams({"invID": component.get("v.recordId") });
    // Set up the callback
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        component.set('v.extras', actionResult.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

  },
})
```